# Installing Plugins to Visual Studio Cordova project

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I have a new blank cordova project that I would like to install a plugin into,

http://plugreg.com/plugin/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin

I've tried the following,

1. open up cmd
2. browse to application folder, containing .sln file
3. install cordova using npm
4. run 'cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin.git'

I receive the following error,

'Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.'

Any idea how I get this to work, assuming that I can that is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CPT3.0 added feature to add custom plugin, now you can use config.xml to add plugin from Git.

You can get more detail to install Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CPT3.0 [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/dn841948#Fragment_Quickstart). CPT3.0 requires to uninstall CPT2.0 and install Visual Studio Update 4 before installing CPT3.0

[image]

Comment: Wonderful answer, but please explain what CPT means if you're going to use it as the main solution.

Comment: CPT -- refers technical preview release. Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova has RTM (release to manufacture) and RTM > CPT. It is just used to indicate pre-release

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your solution only contains the www folder of a phonegap plugin. While the actual root folder of a real phonegap application is a level above the www folder and contains folders like platform and others. Make sure the execute the command on the folder on level above or it won't recognize it indeed!

Comment: Cheers, I shall give that a try in the morning!

Comment: Cool! Keep me posted. :)

Comment: I had to navigate to bld\Debug\ to find any semblance of a www folder anywhere and ran the command, it processed it but returned an error.  Oddly enough the error is identical to if I add the following entry to config.xml,

Comment: <vs:features>
    <vs:feature>https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin.git</vs:feature>
  </vs:features>

Comment: Error: Variable(s) missing: URL_SCHEME

Comment: I used the following addition to the command and it completed,

-variable URL_SCHEME=mycustomscheme

but i don't think it persists, as visual studio is supposed to generate all of this, so any idea how to do this in visual studio cordova apps?

Comment: I've now added the plugin into a plugins folder in my solution which seems a lot nicer but i need to be able to supply this parameter somehow but not sure where.

Comment: looking at the output visual studio calls this,

Calling plugman.install on plugin "C:\myapps\CustomURLScheme\CustomURLScheme\bld\Debug\plugins\nl.x-services.plugins.launchmyapp" for platform "android" with options "{"cli_variables":{}}"

so i need to add a parameter to that call somehow

Comment: Okay so I have it now, create a folder called plugins in the project root, download the git repository to it, so the www folder is in a sub folder in plugins, like plugins\myplugin\www  then edit the plugin.xml file so that the parameter elements now become param elemenets, and add a value attribute to them with your desired value in.

Comment: yes, right way to do is to plugin.xml since visual studio currently does not support passing parameter to plugin through config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

okay so what you do is as follows,

1. create a 'plugins' folder in your project root
2. download the plugin git repository
3. unpack the git repository to the plugins folder created in 1, so your folder structure should look something like myproject\plugins\myplugin\plugin.xml
4. edit the plugin.xml
5. change any preference elements as follows,

so the following is change like so, preference to param

```
<preference name="URL_SCHEME" />
<param name="URL_SCHEME" value="myvdesiredvalue" />
```