# how to hide the keyboard in a multi device hybrid app

Tags: keyboard, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have a javascript based multi-device-hybrid-app that targets both IOS and Andriod and cannot find any information on how to hide the keyboard when a submit button is clicked.

How would I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ionic Cordova plugin to hide keyboard, you can download the plugin from [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard)

cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

Refer SO post '[Installing Plugins to Visual Studio Cordova project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721215/installing-plugins-to-visual-studio-cordova-project/26919998#26919998)' to add custom plugin from Git in Visual Studio